# Apple rejects iPhone Build for showing Test Ads on App

Tags: objective-c, swift, iphone

i Have integrate Ads Mob on my app for real or live add ,its working fine on simulator and Testing device and other client device it shoes live ads. but when this build uploaded to the apple store app connect on app store, they are got Test add on my device and reject the build, i do not find the exact scenario of  reject the build due to test add, since i have integrated live ads banner id of Ads Mob, i do not find the solution app store how to find test add.
  please help me if you got my query.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is check where you define your adUnitID in the app.

The easiest way to do that would be to use Command + Shift + F (Find) to search your entire workspace for the string "ca-app-pub" (which I believe is the beginning of any adUnitID), and ensure that the only string being used is the Live Ad string from the AdMob website for the ad in question.

If that doesn't reveal any issues, please share the snippets of code where you define and present the ad.

Comment: thanks lukemmtt for answering ,
 i have test according to you "ca-app-pub" text into entire application , i got two place where "ca-app-pub" key is used, one where adsUnit id require and other is AppId is required is configured into the info list, our Test device live add are showing but it get test add when do upload build on app store , still  i am stuck to find solution.